# config.Runtime doesn't work after build

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I've created config.Runtime js in my app and everything working fine , I'm able to set and get the parameters in it .

```
Ext.define('TaskTouch.config.Runtime', {
singleton: true,
config: {
    selectedCategory: 0,
    serviceURL : 'resources/service.asmx/'
},
constructor: function (config) {
    this.initConfig(config);
}
```

});

Thing is that after I build my app I get the following error :

```
Error evaluating http://localhost:44092/TaskTouch/build/production/TaskTouch/app.js with message: TypeError: TaskTouch.config.Runtime is undefined
```

I do require it :

```
Ext.require([
'Ext.MessageBox',
'Ext.Panel',
'Ext.data.Store',


  'TaskTouch.config.Runtime'
]);

Ext.application({....
```

So I have no idea why it doesn't work after build (maybe something I need to update in app.json ?!)

Comment: Where have you kept your config folder, within app folder or outside it?

Comment: inside app folder same as controller/model/profile...

Answer (score 0):

Check "TaskTouch.config.Runtime" file name and location... some times its happens due to typographical mistake..

Comment: Its fine , as i said , it stopps working only after build and only in sencha touch 2...